# How can I draw a use case diagram for multiple user privilege?

Tags: uml

I'm try to draw a use case diagram for Human Resource Management System. I have 3 types of users which are Admin, Supervisor and Employee.
Let say:

Example 1:
Admin can access a complete employee management function which can add, edit, view and so on while supervisor can only view the employee information.

Example 2:
In Leave Management, Admin can configure leave but he cannot apply leave while supervisor can't configure leave but he can apply leave and view his leave history.

I'm trying to create a top level use case like employee management and its sub function (add, edit, view, ...) is extend to it. But when I try to connect Supervisor to employee management, I stuck and it is kinda weird if it is connection directly to "view employee" use case which is extend from "Employee Management" use case.

In "Leave Management" use case is more confusing, because Admin and Supervisor have different action as I mentioned at above.

Any suggestion or solution to me? Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

You have to cut out our use cases according to each role as depicted below.[image]

Comment: Thx for answering. I'm just learning draw use case diagram and I just found that the way I'm doing is wrong. Ur example might help me